# VBA - Find cell if contains specific date

Tags: excel, vba, macos, date, find

I am trying find and select a specific cell based on a date taken from another worksheet, in this example dates are in the first row.

[image]

I tried the below code, but it returns nothing every time:

```
Sub Costing()

Dim TargetDate as String,

TargetDate = "06-Oct"

Set x = Sheets("Raw Materials Costs").Range("A1:AK1").Find(TargetDate, after:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues)
Cells(3, x.Column).Select

End Sub
```

Appreciate your help, Thanks.

Comment: are the values stored as dates or strings?

Comment: They are dates, C1 is the actual date and then the next cells are (=cell+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Costing()

    Dim TargetDate As String, x, ar
    
    TargetDate = "06-Oct"
    
    With Sheets("Raw Materials Costs")
        ar = .Range("A1:AK1").Value2
        x = Application.Match(CDbl(CDate(TargetDate)), ar, 0)
        
        If Not IsError(x) Then
            .Cells(3, x).Select
        Else
            MsgBox TargetDate & " not found", vbCritical
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just would like to know what "ar" means.

Comment: @TaherAlaa `ar` is the name I chose for the array of date values. You can `Dim ar as Variant` if it helps.